# Keyframed bones not animating

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, dopesheet

My animation was working fine but after reopening blender and despite the keyframes with the correct values and at the correct spot being present in my dope sheet, my IK bone is not moving anymore (highlighted in red).

Any clue about the "whys" would be highly appreciated!

To me, it looks like blender didn't cash the anim info of the bones linked to the IK bone but I have really no idea why it happened and how I can prevent it in the future (or restaure my animation).

PS: my bones are not locked, but there are on a separate bone layer (like some others which animate just fine).

Cheers.

[image: The renegate bones in my dope sheet]